# Exporting select query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did a select query on sql server and need to do something as basic saving / exporting the result. I chose not to use the 'copy with headers' option on the upper left corner as I loose the leading zero in some of the records whenever I paste directly into excel. I resorted to using the 'save result as' option and saved the result in CSV and TXT. Unfortunately, the records are scattered randomly under different columns. I would really appreciate your help on this.

In summary..my question is....How do I save result so I don't loose the leading zero of a query or how do I copy / paste query result into excel so I don't loose the leading zero..or what do I need to do right so when I save query in csv or txt, columns are not scattered around.

Many thanks

Comment: Use copy and paste. But before you paste, change the whole sheet to Text (or just the columns  you want leading zeros), then paste it. This will preserve the leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks for this. How about if I need to save a query in CSV, TXT BUT need to ensure when opened in Excel, records in rows are not scattered in different columns.?

Comment: use BCP to export into csv or txt.

Comment: I vote to close this as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the results, including the column headers into notepad.  Save and close the file.  Use excel to open the file.

In the Text Import Wizard, choose Delimited - Tab.  Then designate the appropriate columns as text.